# How to decompress mongo journal files

Tags: python, mongodb, snappy, journal

As I have explored, journal files created by Mongodb is compressed using snappy compression algorithm. but I am not able to decompress this compressed journal file. It gives an error on trying to decompress

> Error stream missing snappy identifier

the python code I have used to decompress is as follows:

```
import collections
import bson
from bson.codec_options import CodecOptions
import snappy
from cStringIO import StringIO
try:
    with open('journal/WiredTigerLog.0000000011') as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        fh = StringIO()
        snappy.stream_decompress(StringIO("".join(content)),fh)
        print fh
except Exception,e:
    print str(e)
    pass
```

please help i can't make my way after this

Comment: Maybe your journal isn't compressed. Try to open it in a hex-editor and see if you can read your plain data.

Comment: Ditto what @RetoAebersold said. [It seems to not be finding the expected Snappy header](https://github.com/andrix/python-snappy/blob/master/snappy.py#L213).

Comment: Tried your code snippet and it worked on framed snappy data.  Adding to what others noted, if you open the file in a hex editor, it should be apparent whether it's snappy framed data.  The signature is (starting at file offset zero): `\377\006\0\0sNaPpY` as from *nix magic file or `ff06 0000 734e 6150 7059` in hex.  Perhaps the WiredTiger Storage Engine is writing using a [different compression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#compression) option?

Answer (score 1):

> There's two forms of Snappy compression, the basic form and the
>   streaming form. The basic form has the limitation that it all must fit
>   in memory, so the streaming form exists to be able to compress larger
>   amounts of data. The streaming format has a header and then subranges
>   that are compressed. If the header is missing, it sounds like maybe
>   you compressed using the basic form and are trying to uncompress with
>   the streaming form.
>   https://github.com/andrix/python-snappy/issues/40

If that is the case, use `decompress` instead of `stream_decompress`.

But if could be that the data isn't compressed at all:

```
with open('journal/WiredTigerLog.0000000011') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

could work.

> Minimum log record size for WiredTiger is 128 bytes. If a log record is 128 bytes or smaller, WiredTiger does not compress that record.
>   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/journaling/

Comment: Since WiredTiger only compresses records which are larger that 128 bytes. How will we detect that which lines are compressed and which are not?